# Lead window function with duplicate dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

Sample data here:
http://rextester.com/VNGMF66717

I have the following data:

```
  ID    Year    Date    
1111    2016    2016-02-28
1111    2016    2016-02-28
1111    2016    2016-03-31
1111    2016    2016-03-31
1111    2016    2016-03-31
1111    2016    2016-04-02
1111    2016    2016-05-31
1111    2016    2016-08-01
1111    2016    2016-12-11
1111    2017    2017-01-02
1111    2017    2017-01-02
1111    2017    2017-02-04
1111    2017    2017-02-04
1111    2017    2017-07-08
2222    2016    2016-02-11
2222    2016    2016-02-11
2222    2016    2016-03-28
2222    2016    2016-03-28
2222    2016    2016-03-28
2222    2016    2016-07-22
2222    2016    2016-12-31
2222    2017    2017-02-01
2222    2017    2017-02-14
```

I want to add a NextDate column (that resets within each ID and year) using a lead window-function directly in the SELECT statement, **instead of a self join** using a RANK windowfunction as i did in the provided example.

The NextDate column should be exactly like this

```
  ID    Year    Date        NextDate
1111    2016    2016-02-28  2016-03-31
1111    2016    2016-02-28  2016-03-31
1111    2016    2016-03-31  2016-04-02
1111    2016    2016-03-31  2016-04-02
1111    2016    2016-03-31  2016-04-02
1111    2016    2016-04-02  2016-05-31
1111    2016    2016-05-31  2016-08-01
1111    2016    2016-08-01  2016-12-11
1111    2016    2016-12-11  NULL
1111    2017    2017-01-02  2017-02-04
1111    2017    2017-01-02  2017-02-04
1111    2017    2017-02-04  2017-07-08
1111    2017    2017-02-04  2017-07-08
1111    2017    2017-07-08  NULL
2222    2016    2016-02-11  2016-03-28
2222    2016    2016-02-11  2016-03-28
2222    2016    2016-03-28  2016-07-22
2222    2016    2016-03-28  2016-07-22
2222    2016    2016-03-28  2016-07-22
2222    2016    2016-07-22  2016-12-31
2222    2016    2016-12-31  NULL
2222    2017    2017-02-01  2017-02-14
2222    2017    2017-02-14  NULL
```

Anyone know how to do this properly?

Comment: What you tried?

Comment: please add your rextester code to the post to avoid relying on the link.

Comment: @Lali:In the link ,user provided sample data ,along with what he tried

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may not be exactly what you meant, but by using two window functions with a nested select : MAX(LEAD), you get the desired result.

```
select
    id, yr, dt
    ,MAX(nx_dt) OVER (PARTITION BY id, dt) nxt_dt
FROM
    (
        select 
            *
            , LEAD(dt) OVER (PARTITION BY id, yr ORDER BY id, yr, dt) nx_dt
        from
        #testtable
    ) sub

/*
drop table #testtable

create table #testtable
(
    id int, yr int, dt date
)
insert into #testtable
(
    id, yr, dt
)
SELECT 1111,2016,'2016-02-28'   union all
SELECT 1111,2016,'2016-02-28'   union all
SELECT 1111,2016,'2016-03-31'   union all
SELECT 1111,2016,'2016-03-31'   union all
SELECT 1111,2016,'2016-03-31'   union all
SELECT 1111,2016,'2016-04-02'   union all
SELECT 1111,2016,'2016-05-31'   union all
SELECT 1111,2016,'2016-08-01'   union all
SELECT 1111,2016,'2016-12-11'   union all
SELECT 1111,2017,'2017-01-02'   union all
SELECT 1111,2017,'2017-01-02'   union all
SELECT 1111,2017,'2017-02-04'   union all
SELECT 1111,2017,'2017-02-04'   union all
SELECT 1111,2017,'2017-07-08'   union all
SELECT 2222,2016,'2016-02-11'   union all
SELECT 2222,2016,'2016-02-11'   union all
SELECT 2222,2016,'2016-03-28'   union all
SELECT 2222,2016,'2016-03-28'   union all
SELECT 2222,2016,'2016-03-28'   union all
SELECT 2222,2016,'2016-07-22'   union all
SELECT 2222,2016,'2016-12-31'   union all
SELECT 2222,2017,'2017-02-01'   union all
SELECT 2222,2017,'2017-02-14'
*/
```

Answer (score 3):

I this you need to do this with `outer apply` or a subquery:

```
select cte.*, next_cte.date
from cte outer apply
     (select top 1 cte2.*
      from cte cte2
      where cte2.id = cte.id and cte2.year = cte.year and
            cte2.date > cte.date
      order by cte2.date desc
     ) next_cte;
```

Another alternative is to do the `lead()` on distinct values:

```
select cte.*, cte_next.next_date
from cte join
     (select id, year, date,
             lead(date) over (partition by id, year order by date) as next_date
      from cte
      group by id, year, date
     ) cte_next
     ON cte.id = cte_next.id and cte.year = cte_next.year and cte.date = cte_next.date;
```

Comment: It's not possible (or maybe not even feasible) to avoid making a sub-query/outer apply to get the desired result?

Comment: @EmilVissing . . . I  don't think so, but perhaps someone else will come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be using a correlated sub-query, which gets the next date in a year if `LEAD` returns the same date as current date for an id.

```
SELECT 
      [ID]
     ,[Year]
     ,[Date]
     ,CASE WHEN LEAD([Date]) OVER(PARTITION BY [ID],[Year] ORDER BY [Date]) = [Date]
      THEN (SELECT MIN([Date]) FROM CTE WHERE [Date]>c.[Date] and [ID]=c.[ID] and [Year]=c.[Year])
      ELSE LEAD([Date]) OVER(PARTITION BY [ID],[Year] ORDER BY [Date]) END AS [NextDate]
FROM CTE C
```